# Start an action with a button when one is already going on

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, core-animation

When I click a `UIButton`, say `b1`, two random values, `x` and `y`, are generated which become the new coordinates of another `UIButton`, say `b2`. `b2` slowly moves to the required position (using `+[UIView animateWithDuration: animations:]` ). Now what I want to happen is: while `b2` is in motion, clicking `b1` again should move `b2` to the new coordinates. What's happening right now is that I'm unable to click on `b1` until `b2` is nicely settled in the generated position. Any insights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

instead. And set `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` in the options so that iOS doesn't block user interaction when the animation is occurring.

You'll also want to set `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` so that the button begins at the current state.